# An Analysis Question from past qual

Tags: real-analysis

I am almost positive that the following statement is true, but I am not sure how to formally prove it.  Any help would be wonderful.

If $m(E) < \infty$ and $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, is it true that $m(E\cap(E + t)) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty?$

Answer (score 2):

Take $R$ so that $m(E \backslash [-R,R]) < \epsilon$.  What can you say about $m(E \cap (E+t))$ if $|t| > 2R$?